# Cypher - is it possible to declare common table expression over synthetized data?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, common-table-expression

To play with SQL or explain some language feature, it is often unnecessary to have data in real database table, only common table expression suffices:

```sql
with my_sample (id, name, age) as (values
  (1, 'Alice', 17),
  (2, 'Bob', 19)
), can_drive_car (name) as (
  select name from my_sample where age >= 18
)
select * from can_drive_car
```

Does anything equivalent exist in Cypher? I mean create graph on-the-fly, query it and return result without impact to data in database. Pseudocode:

```
WITH CREATE (:Person {name:'Alice'})-[:FRIEND]->(:Person {name:'Bob'})-[:FRIEND]->(:Person {name:'Charlie'})
MATCH p=shortestPath((a {name:'Alice'})-[*]->(c {name:'Charlie'}))
RETURN p
```

I am aware of Cypher `WITH` clause. Despite same naming it seems to me that in Cypher - unlike SQL - the clause only passes result of previous query part (which was invoked on real graph data in Neo4j database) to subsequent streaming, AFAIK it cannot fabricate anything beyond as in my SQL example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly I've not found anything that fits 100% of the bill, but there are a few tools that might give you some more flexibility in this area:

1. Virtual Nodes and Relationships

https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/virtual/virtual-nodes-rels/. These are nodes and rels that live for the duration of the query. However, they're for visualisation only, and you can't perform matches on them. For example, this returns the virtual nodes & rels:

```
CALL apoc.create.vNode(['Person'],{name:'Alice'}) yield node as a
CALL apoc.create.vNode(['Person'],{name:'Bob'}) yield node as b
CALL apoc.create.vNode(['Person'],{name:'Charlie'}) yield node as c
CALL apoc.create.vRelationship(a, 'FRIEND', {}, b) yield rel as rel1
CALL apoc.create.vRelationship(b, 'FRIEND', {}, c) yield rel as rel2
RETURN *
```

However, as soon as you add in a MATCH statement, it returns nothing.

```
CALL apoc.create.vNode(['Person'],{name:'Alice'}) yield node as a
CALL apoc.create.vNode(['Person'],{name:'Bob'}) yield node as b
CALL apoc.create.vNode(['Person'],{name:'Charlie'}) yield node as c
CALL apoc.create.vRelationship(a, 'FRIEND', {}, b) yield rel as rel1
CALL apoc.create.vRelationship(b, 'FRIEND', {}, c) yield rel as rel2
MATCH p=shortestPath((a)-[*]->(c))
RETURN p
```

2. Virtual Resources

https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/virtual-resource/ This is a way of querying external data sources at the same time as your neo4j nodes. The data from the external source is not brought into the main graph, but you *can* do queries with the nodes from the virtual resource. However, it doesn't fit the bill, because there doesn't seem to be an easy way of making this self-contained. You'd need to have an external resource containing the "virtual" data. It can be as simple as a CSV file, but nevertheless.

3. Graph Projections, using the Graph Data Science library

The GDS library performs its operation on a graph projection, rather than the  written-to-disk copy of the data, like a temporary table in SQL. You can to filter the nodes and relationships to work with a smaller dataset. However, you can't add new nodes to the graph projection.

I agree it would be very useful to have something like this though - I hope one turns up!

Comment: Thanks for exhaustive answer. Although I chose different solution for my problem (it was about finding a path in very trivial graph - I finally implemented algorithm in Java client), your answer gave me valuable insight into Neo4j possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick (and dirty) solution, I usually approach this problem by adding an extra test label to the nodes I'm creating, eg:

```
CREATE (:Person:Test {name:'Alice'})-[:WORKS_FOR]->(:Manager:Test {name:'Bob'})-[:DRIVES]->(:Car:Test {name:'Ford Cortina'})
```

Then, when I've finised `MATCH(x:Test) DETACH DELETE x` clears everything up.

Not ideal, but might work for you if your testing is simple.

Comment: My thanks for similar reason as in case of @fahran's answer. I found it useful to clean after experiments.